# help with meromorphic doubly periodic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series, elliptic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Given a non constant meromorphic doubly periodic function $f$ with real-independent periodes $f(z+\omega_1)=f(z+\omega_2)=f(z)$. Consider $F:=\{\lambda_1\omega_1+\lambda_2 \omega_2, \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in [0,1]\}$. Prove that $f$ has the same number of poles and zeros on $F$ with multiplicities counted.

I tried basically everything (Laurent-series etc.) but what I'm missing is that I need to prove the hint: $f$ has no poles and zeroes on the boundary of $F$.

I know that $\partial F$ is a contour and for the rest of the exercises I can use the Argument Principle but I really don't know how to prove the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). Integration of $f'/f$ on the contour $\partial F$ is possible, and the result is

- the number of zeros minus the number of poles, multiplicities counted, on the one side, and
- zero, on the other side, because contour integrals on opposite sides of the fundamental parallelogram $F$ cancel each other, same values, opposite direction of the contour paths.

Comment: But how do I know that $f$ has no poles on $\partial F$? I noticed that the path integral over $\partial F$ its zero either way, because $f$ is periodic. Does that imply that there are no zeroes on the boundary?

Comment: $f$ can have some zero & poles on $\partial F$, but nothing prevents from replacing $F$ by $F+\epsilon$. And you need to define $F:=\{\lambda_1\omega_1+\lambda_2 \omega_2, \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in [0,1)\}$ to get that the number of zeros & poles is the same even when some of them are on $\partial F$. @BenjaminSt.

Comment: The OP was mentioning "Use the hint: $f$ has no poles and zeros on the boundary of $F$", so i assumed there are none there. If there are such poles and/or zeros, then they are building a discrete set. Then use as fundamental domain a translated version of $F$ which shows no collision in the boundary with poles and zeros of $f$. Each such translated version is good.

Comment: I'm thinking that there maybe an error in the exercises... Is there any double periodic function which does have a zero/pole on its boundary?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions, the $\wp$-function has a pole in zero...